# Django: Create QuerySet baed on number of one-to-many obejcts in DB

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, if I have two models Question and Choice with a one-to-many relationship how can I filter a Manager of Question objects to create a QuerySet that only contains Ones that have one or more Choices?

The current code is as follows and it refers to a view that displays a list of Questions according to certain criteria:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

The view displays the five more recent Questions that have a pub_date field not located in the future time. I know I could access the value I need with something along these lines:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
for q in questions:
    number_of_choices = q.choice_set.count()
```

But I need the get_queryset method to return a QuerySet while accessing choice_set requires to execute the query and extract a question from the result.

So, how can I filter that QuerySet based on its choice_set attribute?

(This is a challenge proposed in the "Ideas for more tests" section of the Part 5 of the tutorial on the Django website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work and it should be the idiomatic method to use with Django:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those
        set to be published in the future or questions without choices).
        """
        return Question.objects.annotate(
            choice_count=Count('choice')
        ).filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
            choice_count__gt=0
        ).distinct().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

This is an edit of a previous answer that offered this solution, whose efficiency I wasn't convinced with.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
        choice__id__gt=0
    ).distinct().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want to check if Question has choices or not.

If I were you, I'd use `exists()`

Here's code:

```
# models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="choices")
```

```
# views.py

def test_question_has_choices(question):
    if question.choices.exists():
        return "Question has choices."
    else:
        return "Question has no choices."
```

If question has choices, `test_question_has_choices` will return "Question has choices.".

If not, will return "Question has no choices."

Comment: It's similar to what I meant, but not exactly. I'm writing a view that will return a list of Questions. I'll update my question with more details.